# Save mobile client from downloading large image with responsive design

Tags: javascript, css, html, responsive-design, mobile-website

As responsive design is becoming more popular now, one of the drawback for responsive design is mobile client need to download the un-needed large images, e.g.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

The page scale very well on my iPhone, but the image downloed is `1500x550`, which is wasted, slow and for some users, it incurred cost.

What would be the alternative approach, when I know the client is mobile, don't serve the large image? Are there any existing method/libray so I don't need to write my own UA sniffing code?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.w3.org/community/respimg/ and http://responsiveimages.org/

It's a W3 working group that is going to create a **specification for responsive images**:

http://picture.responsiveimages.org/

For now, you can use a **polyfill** written in javascript which has a similar syntax and it's maintained by the same guys accordingly to their own spec:

https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill

I've tested it and i'm going to use it in production because it works brilliantly ;)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article, [Media Query Asset Downloading](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/). I found that making the images a background image wrapped in another element works best.

This is a very common question, and a good one and there is not a 'best answer' yet.

Here is an article on the [Clown Car technique](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/02/clown-car-technique-solving-for-adaptive-images-in-responsive-web-design/)

I hope this helps you out. I am glad you are concerned about the images on the different devices, this is a commonly overlooked issue.

Answer (score 0):

If using the Clown Car technique, see my notes on making it work properly in IE:
http://jona.ca/blog/notes-on-using-the-clown-car-technique-in-ie